# MSSQL 2014 Format function is not recognized

Tags: t-sql, format, management-studio-express

I'm using `MicrosoftSQL Server 2014` and `Management Studio` version 12.0.4100.1 and trying to use `Format` function to do the following:

`Format([money spent], 'C', 'en-us') as 'You Spent'`

When executing that statement I get the following error:

**'format' is not a recognized built-in function name.**

I tried to change compatibility level as well, changing to 110 did not work by saying that **Valid values of the database compatibility level are 80, 90, or 100**

Is there is an alternative that I can use to achieve the same result, or I still can use `Format` function after changing some other settings?

Comment: What is the data type of [money spent]

Comment: Also are you sure the database you are connecting to is 2014? Try `select @@version` and what do you see

Comment: data type of [money spent] is `money`

Comment: @SQLChao, Oh, actually, database I'm connecting to is Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP1). That is the problem. Format is not recognized. I looked in the "Help" menu and saw some version numbers for management studio and SQL Server, but actual database version is 2008

Comment: You'll have to write some TSQL to manually format `money spent`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `FORMAT()` is not supported in 2008 you have to manually format. You can try something like

```
SELECT '$' + CAST(ROUND([money spent], 2) AS VARCHAR(25))
```